# TryApplyChanges not getting updated actual solution Buildalyzer adhocworkspace

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, workspace

currently I am using .net core with **Buildalyzer** and creating work-space using same and modifying into project but changes is not reflated in my actual solution.

please find below code:

```
AnalyzerManager manager = new AnalyzerManager("G:\test\test.sln");
using (var workspace = manager.GetWorkspace())
 {
       var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
       var newSolution = solution.AddDocument(DocumentInfo.Create(DocumentId.CreateNewId(solution.ProjectIds.FirstOrDefault()), "Test.cs"));
       workspace.TryApplyChanges(newSolution);
 }
```

it adds document in my workspace, however not save in my actual project.

let me know any alternate of MSBuildWorkspace in .net core.